# Create Read Replica of RDS instance using java code

Tags: amazon-web-services, java, amazon-rds

I was googling all the way round to find out a solution for this: Is there a way to create a read repica of an RDS instance using RDS API?

I am creating an application in java which needs to create a read replica of an instance which I mention. Any idea how to do this? Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a read-replica of an RDS instance, you can use the `CreateDBInstanceReadReplica` API method:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_CreateDBInstanceReadReplica.html

Here is the documentation for the AWS SDK for Java:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html

You would use `com.amazonaws.services.rds.AmazonRDS.createDBInstanceReadReplica`

Comment: Thanks. But I am getting a weird error saying that "User: arn:aws:iam::869519277:user/<user> is not authorized to perform: rds:CreateDBInstanceReadReplica (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 5671d9ad-5529-11e5-8494-c78afe1f48cf)"

I am able to create read replica using aws console, but not through java code using api. What could be the issue here.?

Comment: The problem is that the access key  that you are using does not have permission to execute the `rds:CreateDBInstanceReadReplica` command. Add `rds:CreateDBInstanceReadReplica` to your user's IAM policy document.